# Sliderbar en C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms

Tengo un problema y es que quiero hacer un sliderbar en C# con Windows Forms y la verdad no se me ocurre nada.
La idea de la barra deslizante es que yo pueda agregr en cierta posición de la barra una especie de círculo que sea un label, el cual el usuario puede clickear para ir a esa posición en el sliderbar.
El problema es que no encuentro nada para hacer un sliderbar, probé varias cosas con ChatGPT y nada funcionó. Probé yo mismo hacerlo usando HScrollbar pero no pude eliminar las flechas que tiene ese control para modificar su rango.
La idea es que sea algo así pero con botones en una posición que yo como programador decida (https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPYES.png).
¿Podría alguien guiarme un poco?

Probé modificar el control de HScrollBar y cambiando propiedades que tiene HScrollbar un poco a lo loco porque realmente no sabía lo que estaba haciendo. Mi idea era con HScrollbar sacarle las flechas que tiene a los laterales y luego agregar los botones que necesito a mi gusto, pero realmente no sé cómo hacerlo.